# How to grey out buttons on C# forms dependent on a particular instance

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have this method that checks if a service is running and a button which when clicked initaites the method. Although is there a way to "grey out" the button if the service is for example - not installed. ?

```
public static void StopService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
{
    ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
    try
    {
        TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

        service.Stop();
        service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
        MessageBox.Show("The service was successfully turned on");
    }
    catch
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Service is not installed!");
    }
}

private void button14_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StopService("Update Scheduler Service", 20000);
}
```

Comment: You're using WinForms, right?  Should add that as a tag (and possibly to the quesiton text).  The reason I ask is that the solution is different in WPF.  Also, in your example code, you shouldn't catch all exceptions, only the exceptions that tell you for sure that the service aren't installed.  You should let the rest fall through, or log them and rethrow them, or log them and swallow them.  You'll hide bugs and throw up incorrect error messages, otherwise.

Comment: Thats correct, ive updated accordingly

Comment: You still didn't specify whether you're using Winforms or WPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WinForms controls have a .Enabled property that when set to False, the control is grayed out like you wish.  I assume WPF has the same functionality, but I have never used WPF so I can't say for certain.

Comment: He updated the tag to specify WinForms.  WPF is slightly different (I believe `IsEnabled`), and you'd want to use databinding/commands for it...